# What are the gem5 annotations mops magic instructions and how to use them?

Tags: gem5

I was studying the gem5 m5ops implementation, when I came across a related annotation feature that is also exposed through magic instructions / memory accesses: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/f94f70237dfaac86c83dfbb7cb24e6a821b867eb/include/gem5/asm/generic/m5ops.h#L88

```
#define M5OP_ANNOTATE           0x55
#define M5OP_AN_BSM             0x1
#define M5OP_AN_ESM             0x2
#define M5OP_AN_BEGIN           0x3
#define M5OP_AN_END             0x4
#define M5OP_AN_Q               0x6
#define M5OP_AN_DQ              0x7
#define M5OP_AN_WF              0x8
#define M5OP_AN_WE              0x9
#define M5OP_AN_RQ              0xA
#define M5OP_AN_WS              0xB
#define M5OP_AN_SQ              0xC
#define M5OP_AN_AQ              0xD
#define M5OP_AN_PQ              0xE
#define M5OP_AN_L               0xF
#define M5OP_AN_IDENTIFY        0x10
#define M5OP_AN_GETID           0x11
```

but I could not find how to actually use them. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I have been told that this is a somewhat abandoned mechanism, and that you are likely better off using the `WORK_BEGIN` and `WORK_END` ops, which allow you to break into an arbitrary Python script and do whatever the annotations would be doing more sanely, but I haven't tested it out yet myself.